# error programming when using inherit in oodo9

Tags: openerp-8

i am new in oodo9, i have got error when i have try to add a new field into res.partner using inherit, it tell me that the new field does not exist in res.partner, please help me

```
class testtt(models.Model):
_inherit ='res.partner'
_columns = {
    'test_field': fields.char('test field'),        
}
```

**testtt()**

```
<record id="testtt" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name"> test.form </field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position="after">
                <field name="test_field" />                    
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  la colonne res_partner.test_field n'existe pas
LINE 1: ...ent_id" as "parent_id","res_partner"."id" as "id","res_partn...

Comment: Add your py file into the __init__.py file

Comment: thank's a lot for your answer, but i have already added it in init.py

Comment: test_field is not found means that field is not there in pyc file, so either you have not restarted odoo server or that module in which the file added is not in addons path.

Comment: thank's a lot for you help, it works now. thank's a lot